# How to style a 'amp-img' element with styled-components?

Tags: reactjs, amp-html, styled-components

How can I style a custom tag with Styled Components?

I want to style an image with AMP HTML which needs an `amp-img` tag, not a `img`.

Here is what I would like to do:

```
const Image = styled.('amp-img')`
filter: blur(2px);`
```

Thx!

Answer (score 1):

You may refer with this [AMP HTML Components](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-html-components.md) documentation.

> Styling and theming of AMP-provided components is all done via CSS. See the [AMP Spec](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-html-format.md) for more detail.

AMP elements can be styled with class or element selectors using most common CSS properties. Add any styles to an AMP page using a single `<style amp-custom>` tag in the head of the document. For example:

```
<style amp-custom>
  amp-img {
    border: 5px solid black;
  }

  amp-img.grey-placeholder {
    background-color: grey;
  }
</style>
```

Also from this [page](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-img#styling), it stated that `amp-img` can be styled directly via CSS properties. Setting a grey background placeholder for example could be achieved via:

```
amp-img {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm working with [Styled Components](https://www.styled-components.com) for server side rendering. Maybe I didn't express myself well. But I found a [solution](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/494#issuecomment-280024163).

Answer (score 0):

You can't style an amp tag directly via styled components. Instead you can wrap it with a div and style that div.

```
const Image = styled.div
filter: blur(2px);

<Image><amp-img /></Image>
```